# How do I stop a backup from running?

Tags: windows-8, windows-backup

I've got a Windows Backup running, which I want to stop. It is not running on a schedule. It just seems to be stuck running. It's been running for over a day, without any apparent progress, except for the fact that it appears in the system tray as "Backup in progress". This is on a Windows 8 Professional machine. I've tried finding it in the Task Manager to kill it there, but I don't see anything there with the name of "Backup" in it. So, how do I stop this thing running?

Answer (score 1):

Open the control panel and search "backup" that should bring up the backup settings page. Once you are on the control panel window for backup settings from there there should be a button to stop the backup.

Comment: I've found what you're talking about, but it doesn't have a Stop button.

Comment: It's been more than a year later, and I've still got this issue. Again, doing what Scott suggested back on July 22, 2013 in the Control Panel I've searched for backup. All I can find is "File History" and "Save backup copies of your files with File History". It doesn't show me the backup that's been running for over a year. But it's still running. How do I find this "Backup in progress" task/backup/job/whatever-it-is, and stop it?